# How to get a specific cell from a table on a webpage into google sheets?

Tags: xml, google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to get the total distance (23,596) cell from the Away Games table fom this webpage into google sheets:

https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2022_travel.htm

I am not able to import the cell properly using either `IMPORTXML` or `IMPORTHTML`

I looked at source code of the page and tried to specify the class and/or the tagging of the specific cell but I wasn't able to get the right cell.

These are two examples of what I tried

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2022_travel.htm", "[@id="total_mileage"]")
=IMPORTXML("https://www.pro-football-reference.com/teams/nwe/2022_travel.htm", "//td[@class='right iz']")
```

For everything I tried, I either got an error or an "NA" result.

Comment: The distances are calculated dynamically by a piece of javascript within the HTML code, this is why the IMPORTXML/IMPORTHTML is blank. There is nothing for it to return because it's only calculated after the page loads.

Comment: @childnick - thanks that makes sense. Is there any way I can do what I want?

Comment: Not exactly the same but see here (make a copy) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_3kIXZ6Yu3ZLvUaNJsyUB_vyB4UA6tZKq8xx9G9nNEo/edit?usp=sharing